# Using 'this' variable in jQuery fadeIn?

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

I am trying to make a button, which will favorite the thread, using ajax. But it have to only fade in and out the favorited image on the favorited thread.

I am getting the following error:
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token this`

And that is my code line 11:
`$(this + ' .is_favorited').fadeIn("slow");`

Here is the full Javascript source:

```
$(".do_favorite").live("click", function() {
    var item = $(this).closest(".box");
    var content = $(this).attr('data-id');
    alert(content);
    $.post( 'ajax.favorite.php?sid=' + content + '',
        $(this).serialize(),
        function(data) {
            if (data == "1") {
                // Favorite it
                $(this + ' .not_favorited').fadeOut("slow", function (
                    $(this + ' .is_favorited').fadeIn("slow");
                ));
            }else if (data == "2") {
                // Un-Favorite it
                $(this + ' .is_favorited').fadeOut("slow", function (
                    $(this + ' .not_favorited').fadeIn("slow");
                ));
            }else {
                alert("DER SKETE EN FEJL DU");
            }
        }
    );
    return false;
});
```

Hope someone can help me figure this out, as I really need to use `this`, to make it fade only the clicked one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

save your "this" like this

```
    $(".do_favorite").live("click", function() {
        var me = $(this);
        var item = me.closest(".box");
        var content = me.attr('data-id');
        alert(content);
        $.post( 'ajax.favorite.php?sid=' + content + '',
        me.serialize(),
        function(data) {
            if (data == "1") {
            // Favorite it
            me.find(' .not_favorited').fadeOut("slow", function (
                me.find('.is_favorited').fadeIn("slow");
            ));
            }else if (data == "2") {
            // Un-Favorite it
            me.find('.is_favorited').fadeOut("slow", function (
                me.find('.not_favorited').fadeIn("slow");
            ));
            }else {
            alert("DER SKETE EN FEJL DU");
            }
        }
        );
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: This still gives the same error. I really have no idea why, I have used that method before, but not in `$.post`.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it, another problem is that `function (...)` should be changed to `function() {...}`

Answer (score 4):

You need to pass `this` in as [**context**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) in selector or use **[find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)** function on `$(this)`.

Change

```
 $(this + ' .is_favorited').fadeOut("slow", function (
```

To

```
$('.is_favorited', this).fadeOut("slow", function (
```

Using [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method which is call behind the context.

```
$(this).find('.is_favorited').fadeOut("slow", function (
```

**Edit**

If you want to refer the event source element with class do_favorite in post function then you to put it to some temporary variable as you can not refer with `this` in `post`

```
$(".do_favorite").live("click", function() {
    var item = $(this).closest(".box");
    var content = $(this).attr('data-id');
    alert(content);
    do_favorite_OBJECT = $(this);
    $.post( 'ajax.favorite.php?sid=' + content + '',
        do_favorite_OBJECT.serialize(),
        function(data) {
            if (data == "1") {
                // Favorite it
                $('.not_favorited', do_favorite_OBJECT).fadeOut("slow", function (
                    $('.is_favorited', do_favorite_OBJECT).fadeIn("slow");
                ));
            }else if (data == "2") {
                // Un-Favorite it
                $('.is_favorited', do_favorite_OBJECT).fadeOut("slow", function (
                    $('.not_favorited', do_favorite_OBJECT).fadeIn("slow");
                ));
            }else {
                alert("DER SKETE EN FEJL DU");
            }
        }
    );
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Nevermind, I had an error with the `function(...)` which should be `function() {...}`, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

You can write as:

```
$(this).find('.not_favorited')
```

Comment: I tried this aswell, but as @David said, `this` does not work inside `$.post`, thanks trought for the idea.

Comment: @ErikHansen Yes David is right. `this` wont work inside `$.post`

Comment: But, I can't get it work either if I save `this` into a variable and use that instead. I have no idea why, same error is comming out.

Comment: This example just solves the problem of combining selectors. It shows that you can't concatenate `this` with other string.

Comment: You was right, my other problem was that I did my `function` wrong.. I did the function inside the `()` when it should be inside `{}`, so now the answer of @Silly works.

Thanks a lot, to everyone! :D

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
$(".is_favorited", this);
```

or

```
$(this).find(".is_favorited");
```

Comment: Doesn't work either, thanks for the reply. Error is still the same.

Answer (score 1):

`this` inside a `$.post` callback is not the HTML element you think it is. You need to save the element in a variable before calling `$.post`.

Comment: I didn't knew that, thanks for the informations. I have tried to saved `this` into a variable, and then use that instead, but still without luck.

Answer (score 1):

just use:

```
$(this).find('.not_favorited')
```

Comment: Doesn't work either, thanks for the reply. Error is still the same.